# How to write a function that returns probability distribution's entropy in python

Tags: python, math

Been stuck on this function for a while now, I'm not great with mathematics so I don't understand the maths behind this, any help would be appreciated.

The function should return the probability distribution's entropy as said in the title. It would be great if it could be done without importing any modules other that Counter.

Down below is what I've tried so far but it doesn't seem to return the correct answer.
The function takes a probability distribution list made from a histogram. Prob I therefore a list in range 256.

```
def CalcEntropy(prob):
    ent = 0
    if len(prob) <= 1:
        return 0

    counts = Counter()

    for n in prob:
        counts[n] += 1

    probs = [float(c) / len(prob) for c in counts.values()]
    for p in probs:
        if p > 0.:
            ent = p * math.log(p, 2)
        return ent * -1
```

Thanks in advance, let me know if I've been unclear.

Comment: why without importing additional modules? you also use `math`. why only allow `collections.Counter`?

Comment: what is your input `prob`? could you give an example input with corresponding expected output?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. I don't want to give a complete solution since this seems to be homework, but I will offer a few hints:

1. `prob` is a poor name for the input. In context, `prob` is a list of *values* and not probabilities at all. The entire point of `Counter` is to tabulate the occurrences of those values so that you can calculate the probabilities with which those values occur.
2. `counts = Counter()` makes no sense. Note that `prob` doesn't appear in that line. If you want to tabulate the counts of `prob`, then you would need to use `prob` as the input to `Counter`. If you do so, you can skip the loop in which you tabulate the counts. The entire point of `Counter` is to gather those counts.
3. `ent = p * math.log(p, 2)` simply rewrites `ent` in each pass through the loop, discarding previous values. You should be treating `ent` as a running total, using augmented assignment, `+=`, rather than simple assignment, `=`.
4. `return ent` has the wrong level of indentation. You are returning at the end of the first pass through the loop. Shouldn't you wait until the loop is finished?

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I'll delete my earlier comment, since it makes no sense with respect to the revised answer.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for the helpful comments